# GridView: how to delete from database a value from the selected row and dropdownlist = value from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm working on a project but I need to do something and I Couldn't find a way to do it.
I have:

```
1.GridView
Columns:
No|Name|Age|Choose|Where|
1. Joh  21  Yes/No
```

Where Choose column control is a dropdownlist with 2 values : Yes/No
I'm trying to make something like:

```
If dropdownlist.selected value = "Yes" 
{
Insert Dropdownlist Selected value in the database cell "Choose" , and it should insert the value in the current editing row in the database.
And Dropdownlist value to get the value from the database cell.
}
If dropdownlist value = "NO" then delete the value from the database row.
```

How can I do that? or is there another way ?
I'm using sqldatasource to bind the informations from database in the gridview.

THank you

Comment: I don't understand. If the selected value in row0 is 'yes' then insert to DB all the values of the gridview row0? and what about the dropDown? it will get the value from the DB in the specific row index as the row0?

Comment: the values from the gridview are already in the database and the column "Choose" is clean in database, I want if the user is selecting the value Yes , to add it in the same row in the database. and the dropdown will get the value from the database cell .

Comment: @InziIrina Your question is not at all clear. Please try to get assistance in expressing your question in proper language. If user selects "yes" in dropdown, what do u want to be added to db? A value "yes" itself? If so, then why are u getting the same value back to dropdown again?

Comment: Yes The Value(text) YES , I want the dropdown to have the value choosed ( Yes ) .

Comment: Ok, but which value will be in the dropdown? if you said that the value in the DB is empty...

Comment: do you have an identity for each row? the 'NO' column is unique to each row?

Comment: the value in the dropdown will be the value choosed in the dropdownlist . so , I want the dropdown to get the value choosed by user and save it . that's all

Comment: no , every row should has his own settings I mean If I chose Yes to a row only that row will have the value Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, are you binding your dropdown like this inside grid ?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlchoose" runat="server" 
  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Active") %>' >      
  <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> 
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

If so, use this--
Set `AutoPostBack="true" and OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlchoose_SelectedIndexChange"`

On aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlchoose_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        DropDownList ddlchoose= (DropDownList)sender;

        // get reference to the row
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

        //Get the reference of this ddlchoose
        DropDownList refddlchoose = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlchoose");
        Control ddlchooseParent = refddlchoose.Parent;

        int roeid = Convert.ToInt32((gridview1.SelectedRow.FindControl("ID")).ToString());
        if(ddlchoose.SelectedValue=="1")
        {
         //Update method
        Update(roeid , ddlchoose.SelectedValue.Trim());
        }
        else if(ddlchoose.SelectedValue=="0")
        {
        //Delete method
        Delete(roeid);
        }
        gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: thanks , what is actually your code doing? saving the value in the dropdown?

Comment: Its updating or deleting the row of the grid based on selected value which is 1 for yes ,0 for no in dropdowns selectedindex change event.I havnt give the logic of how to update that row or delete, assuming you know how to do that.

Comment: yea but how Can I save the value? shall I use insert into database or there's another method?so If I close the page , the values to be there

Comment: You can insert,update,delete values based on dropdowns selectedvalue inside this ddlchoose_SelectedIndexChange event. If you want to add another row then use insert into query if you want to update same row use update query.